# Lifecycle method choice in lazy-loading component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am code splitting my create-react-app with React Router per the link they provided in their README.md: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/code-splitting-in-create-react-app.html

It describes how to create an `AsyncComponent` to facilitate lazy-loading:

```
export default function asyncComponent(importComponent) {
  class AsyncComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        component: null
      };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
      const { default: component } = await importComponent();

      this.setState({
        component: component
      });
    }

    render() {
      const C = this.state.component;

      return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : null;
    }
  }

  return AsyncComponent;
}
```

Eslint complains about setting state in `componentDidMount`:

`Updating the state after a component mount will trigger a second render() call and can lead to property/layout thrashing.`

Any reason we can't use `componentWillMount` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting state in `componentDidMount` is [not as bad as Eslint makes it sound](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> Calling setState() in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but
>   it is guaranteed to flush during the same tick. This guarantees that
>   even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user
>   won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution
>   because it often causes performance issues. It can, however, be
>   necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure
>   a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or
>   position.

It won't actually cause layout thrashing because everything will execute before the next animation frame. Unless your app is really complex it probably won't make a noticeable difference.

`componentWillMount` is probably fine to use, with the possible exception that if you ever decide to take advantage of [error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#introducing-error-boundaries) you may see things like components calling `componentWillMount`, hitting an error, and failing without going through their entire lifecycle (i.e. `componentWillUnmount`).

For me personally, if I'm setting state synchronously using props or some other known info, I use the constructor. For starting async calls like AJAX, I put it in `componentDidMount` because conceptually, I want the component to successfully mount and render *and then* start the process of hydrating it.